# Redirect after login with YII2

Tags: yii2

For example:
1. A user is trying to access to mypage.php?param=1.
2. He can not to access, because he is not authenticated. 
3. So, He try to log with his google account.
4. He have a access successfully.
**5. Now, I would like to redirect to that user to mypage.php?param=1.**

Comment: Research a bit about it, try coding it and come back if you get stuck. This isn't a "code this for me" service, you post some code and we help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii support user redirect url when they were redirected  by permission rules.
You can find at :

`Yii2::$app->user->returnUrl`

and check then redirect if it does not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Change like this

You could use **Yii::$app->request->referrer** which returns the last page the user was on.

```
$return_url = Yii::$app->request->referrer;     

//var $return_url have previous url

if($return_url!=NULLL){     

   return $this->redirect($return_url);

}

else{   

  return $this->goBack(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 we need to `return()` the result from the action.I think you need to add a `return` in front of your redirect.

```
return $this->redirect('/user/index',302);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//May be this is not proper way but its working for me

//in your common code where you check user is login or not
if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    \Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ['site/login','return'=>\Yii::$app->request->url];
    return $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->user->loginUrl);
}


// and after login

$return_url = \Yii::$app->request->get('return');

if(!empty($return_url)){
    return $this->redirect($return_url);
}else{
    return $this->goBack();
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->getReturnUrl());
```

instead of

```
return $this->goHome();
```